# Android: Unknown MediaPlayer Warning

Tags: android, warnings, media-player

I'm trying to get the duration of the media file using mediaplayer and all works fine but I'm getting a warning in he DDMS as below.

```
10-21 17:30:35.109: W/MediaPlayer(7564): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
```

My code goes as below

```
//mediaPlayer object initiated to get the duration
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

try {
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(AudioListActivity.this, Uri.parse((db_results.get(position)).toString()));
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.stop();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
//getting duration
int durationTime = 0;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
TextView duration = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewDuration);
durationTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
mediaPlayer.release();
```

Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to ignore this warning.

1)comment the line of code MediaPlayer.release(); and notice the logcat;

2)You may need to reset the Mediaplayer object before releasing the mp.
     mp.reset()  after that test it. Because some time this will cause other error like "illegal state exception"

3)If it is concern to you, do the reset it in try/catch and handle the exception.

Answer (score 3):

add: `mediaPlayer.reset();` before `mediaPlayer.release();`